# Barcode Scanner add button inside scanning page

Tags: ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I have implemented Barcode Scanner for my Ionic project for both iOS and Android.
But when my Scanner starts, I want to add a button inside the view and add an event to it.
I am using `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` plugin

Please help me with how to append something inside the scanning view.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have created a service to call the scanner.
Please see this snippet :: 
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                function (result) {  // success
                    deferred.resolve({'error':false, 'result': result});
                }, 
                function (error) {  // failure
                    deferred.resolve({'error':true, 'result': error.toString()});
                }
            );

Comment: @SSen try the answer I have posted below, I tested and it seem to be working.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add stuff to the layout of your scanner, you need to write code in the plugin itself.

YOU CANNOT INTERACT DIRECTLY WITH THE SCANNER FROM THE JS.

**In fact, the plugin you use uses cordova.exec in order to launch the scanner view by passing it arguments.**

- For Android, you just have to know Java and some XML.
- For iOS, you have to know Objective-C / Swift.

For Android, you may have 4 files to modify :

- plugin.xml : home of all you dependencies
- Your_Activity.java : java file which permits to interact with the scanner view itself by calling buttons, textviews, layouts, etc...
- Your_Main.java : java file which gets and returns parameters from the js file of your plugin
- Your_Layout.xml : xml file in res/layout which is composed of xml attributes interpreted by java

Beside that, I found two good plug-ins for cordova/ionic apps from GitHub :

- phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
- tjwoon/csZBar

And there's the expensive one, Scandit, which resolves all of your problems for about 200$ per month, check the pricing for every solution they propose.

If you use their SDK, you may be able to interact with the scanner view from js files because of their work, but they're the only company I know to do that. (perhaps ManateeWorks...)

Under this part is what I've been doing since mid-July, in order to give you ideas.

---

I'm currently making an ANDROID scanner layout for my ionic app.
You can find my GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/aNkM/csZBar), I forked it from tjwoon's csZBar and I added some stuff my ionic app needs.

I guarantee nothing, but I'm pretty sure I'll implement an iOS layout soon (at least I'll try), and unfortunately I don't really know android / iOS mobile programming.

[Here's a screenshot of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FOHW.jpg)

I made a "tab bar" composed of 3 image buttons, a "top bar" composed of text views & image buttons. The scanner is embedded between these two.

There are pop-ups for the app's features, which pause the scanner and respond to click events.

See the README and Java files (csZBar/android/) for more information.

Don't hesitate to ask questions and/or inspect my code.

---

## Warning

- 1) It's currently on development so use it at your own risks (use branch master, not develop)
- 2) I only modified the android part, not the iOS!
- 3) It doesn't work for Windows phone...

Answer (score 0):

After adding plugin, [install`ngCordova`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) with `bower install ngCordova`

Add link to `ng-cordova.js` JS file above reference to `cordova.js`:

**index.html**

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Also, don't forget to add ngCordova module:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

Now you're ready to use the plugin like this:

**Controller:**

```
var module = angular.module('starter.controllers', []);
module.controller('BarcodeCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    $scope.scan = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner
          .scan()
          .then(function(barcodeData) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(barcodeData));
          }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
          });
      };
  });
});
```

**View:**

```
<button ng-click="scan()">Scan</button>
```

Comment: Prashant, This is already working. But this simply opens the scanner having a text message "Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it." at the bottom of page.
I need to add a button above this text.

Comment: For me, I'm able to scan QR/BarCode and alert the values. Sorry that I misunderstood, but what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Yes that I am able to do as well. But now I need to add a button inside the scanner view so that I can revert back to some page incase I want to quit the scanning process.

Comment: I doubt if the you can add custom button in the camera view, coz everything is controlled by the plugin once you're in that view (and documentation does not show any of that). I could see a `Cancel` button for iOS, IDK about android tho.

Comment: I need to implement in windows too. And no, there is no cancel button visible in android. So I have to include a button inside. I have seen in mobile apps, a button being included, so there has to be some way out. I'll keep trying. Please do let me know if you find a way too.

Comment: Have you tried using back button (or assigning event to back button click) for android? Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674832/cordova-barcode-scanner-on-android-cancel-scan-and-return-to-app

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this? Please guide.